# Debian depmod kernel error

Tags: debian, apt, kernel, ovh

I have run an apt-dist upgrade on my dedicated server that uses a kernel from the provider and I am getting the following error:

```
MTL ➜  ~ apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  ovhkernel-4.9-xxxx-std-ipv6-image
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/10.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 61164 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ovhkernel-4.9-xxxx-std-ipv6-image_4.9.159-599550_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ovhkernel-4.9-xxxx-std-ipv6-image (4.9.159-599550) over (4.9.158-590910) ...
Setting up ovhkernel-4.9-xxxx-std-ipv6-image (4.9.159-599550) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.9.159-xxxx-std-ipv6-64
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.9.159-xxxx-std-ipv6-64
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.9.159-xxxx-std-ipv6-64: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_SUPVlB/lib/modules/4.9.159-xxxx-std-ipv6-64/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_SUPVlB/lib/modules/4.9.159-xxxx-std-ipv6-64/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.159-xxxx-std-ipv6-64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.9.159-xxxx-std-ipv6-64
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
```

I am concerned that this could cause the machine not to boot anymore but I see that the grub config file has been created and installed.  Is it anything to worry about? I cannot understand as I have another dedicated server with exactly the same config with the same provider and it has no issues.

Comment: I never liked OVH's kernels, and I never could figure out why they provide them at all. I always have my dedicated servers boot the distribution kernel.

Comment: OK. Do you know if it is possible to switch from the OVH one to a standard one? I thought that by using a OVH kernel I would stay on the safe side.

Comment: The OVH kernel is pointless. A normal Debian kernel perfectly handles all the hardware, and doesn't cause problems like this. Install the normal Debian kernel `linux-image-amd64` and then remove the OVH kernel. Then see [here](https://serverfault.com/a/793738/126632) for how to reconfigure OVH netboot.

Comment: Speaking just as a Linux sysadmin... Missing the modules for a kernel entirely and yet still having the kernel installed as something to boot sounds like a really bad mistake unless the kernel has everything built into it - which they could do feasibly if they're providing the hardware and a consistent virtualized environment. But even if they're doing that, they should either modify the process to handle no modules directory or provide a minimal modules directory to appease depmod. Since they didn't, I wouldn't trust them to have this stuff working. I mean this looks really bad...

Comment: Thanks. In any case was checking now the config file and all the config options are set to YES so the kernel is monolithic. I think there shouldn't be any issues.. What do you think? Thanks a lot!